# How to replace the hostname portion with xauth (OLD: How to redirect output of xauth command?)

Tags: x11, xorg, xauth

I would like to generate a new `Xauthority` file using `xauth` with another hostname portion and write it to a different file name (as opposed to `~/.Xauthority` where the xauth command typically writes to).

[Later on I want to copy this file to another machine with a different hostname. This machine is a container which binds the X socket but does not have the xauth command installed.]

UPDATE: `xauth extract ~/.newXauthority $DISPLAY` does almost what I want except it does not alter the hostname portion.

I did not find anything useful in `xauth`'s man page.

Comment: @steeldriver: I think you were correct with the -f option, please excuse my wrong statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 sorts of hostname entries managed by `xauth`, local names such as `myhost/unix:0` and remote names such as `remote:0`. The latter are held as ip addresses, but I imagine you are referring to the local names.

The hostname part of these are not actually of any significance to X11, but can be used by the `xdm` tools to distinguish between several local name entries, each with different keys. To change this name simply list the entry you want, take the key at the end of the line, and provide it to the `add` command with your new hostname:

```
xauth -f ~/.newXauthority add newhostname/unix:0 . $(xauth list "$DISPLAY" |awk '{print $NF}')
```

This assumes DISPLAY is `:0`, and you want the same local display number on the new machine.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed and a great explanation :)